# Nested interfaces / types across multiple files?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-typings

I currently have a backend / frontend application that uses a shared `types` folder which contains all of the request / response body interfaces. As the application has grown, we're ending up with some comically long interface names such as `ShippingPlateListShippingPlateStatusRequest` or `ShippingPlateListShippingPlateStatusResponseBody`. While not the end of the world and auto-complete definitely helps they're still pretty hard to read at a glance.

Ideally, I could refactor this so we could just import `ShippingPlate` and then reference it like this: `ShippingPlate.List.ShippingPlateStatus.Request` or `ShippingPlate.List.ShippingPlateStatus.Response.Body`.

Namespaces seem to fit the bill for this, however the interfaces are all kept in separate files. For the interfaces I mentioned, along with interfaces for two other request/response pairs it looks something like this:

```
types/shipping-plate/list/shipping-plate-status/index.ts
types/shipping-plate/list/shipping-plate-status/request.interface.ts
types/shipping-plate/list/shipping-plate-status/response.interface.ts

types/shipping-plate/list/shipping-plate-type/index.ts
types/shipping-plate/list/shipping-plate-type/request.interface.ts
types/shipping-plate/list/shipping-plate-type/response.interface.ts

types/shipping-plate/list/index.ts

types/shipping-plate/shipping-plate/index.ts
types/shipping-plate/shipping-plate/request.interface.ts
types/shipping-plate/shipping-plate/response.interface.ts

types/shipping-plate/index.ts
```

Aside from namespaces, which seemed to cause more problems than it was worth (this is a fully ES Module code base), is there any way to make this work across multiple files? Is there another approach I can take that would make this work?